# Using jquery's .queue to queue functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue

When i remove the parameter 'ajax' from from the `.queue()` function, my ajax calls do get queued. The only problem is, the jQuery docs say that the `.queue()` function will then default to the 'fx' queue. Unfortunately, I am already using this queue (for effects) and I want to use another queue specifically for custom functions. Unfortunately, the code inside the `.queue()` function never gets called. I have an example of my code below (just a small snippet). It is getting a little complicated if you have further questions feel free to comment.

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {

var target = event.target;
var ajaxify = new Ajaxify();

$.each(ajaxify.functions, function(index, value){

     if ($(target).hasClass(value)) {        
       console.log('this is in my console, and nowhere else in my code');
       $('#main').queue('customfunctions', function (next) {
         var self = this;          
         ajaxify[value](target, event, next, self);       
       });

     }

   });
  $('#main').dequeue('customfunctions');
});

function Ajaxify() {

  this.functions = [
                   'ajaxify_overlay',
                   'ajaxify_overlayCancel',
                   'ajaxify_overlaySubmit',
                   'ajaxify_rollout',
                   'ajaxify_rolloutCancel',
                   'ajaxify_rolloutSubmit',
                   'ajaxify_upload',
                   'ajaxify_contentArea',
                   'ajaxify_itemToggler',
                   'ajaxify_closer',
                   'ajaxify_submit',
                   'ajaxify_inputActivate',
                   'ajaxify_executeAndRefresh',
                   'ajaxify_empty' //no comma on the last entry!!!!  
                 ];

}

Ajaxify.prototype.ajaxify_executeAndRefresh = function (target, event, next, self) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var newPath = getVar($(target).attr('class'), 'url'); //getVar function not included, it will get the new path for the ajax call below

  var url = $(target).attr('href');

  $.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    success: function(transport) {

      refreshPage(newPath); //refreshPage function not included, it will do a page refresh with the new path

      next();     

    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) to run the next function in the queue.

Comment: @SLaks: adding .dequeue() does not seem to fix this. I am updating my code above to reflect my addition of .dequeue

Comment: @bmarti: However, it doesn't do anything useful.  It simply calls each function immediately.  You should figure out _when_ to dequeue.

Comment: @SLaks: i put the $(self).dequeue('customfunctions'); inside the success callback for my ajax call. I changed my code above to reflect these changes. It still does not seem to be working though.

Comment: @bmarti: You never kicked off the initial item.

Comment: @SLaks: What do you mean by "never kicked off the intial item"? I added a console.log() to the code above, this shows in my js console. Thanks for your help on this by the way.

Comment: @bmarti: Your code queues a bunch of items.  After each item finishes, you dequeue the next one.  However, where do you dequeue the first item to set the process going?

Comment: @SLaks: In the code above, the first time I call .dequeue() appears in the function Ajaxify.prototype.ajaxify_executeAndRefresh (which is added dynamically to the Ajaxify class on page load). In this function is an ajax call. Inside the ajax call is the success callback. In the success callback, I call the .dequeue() function. Should I call this somewhere else first?

Comment: @bmarti: Yes.  Otherwise how (where) will the first item be dequeued?

Comment: @SLaks: I think I see what your saying. After i do a .each and I have queued up all the functions I want to run, I execute .dequeue() to start the dequeuing process?

Comment: @SLaks: +1 works great thank you for sticking with me through this